# How Center Components Using Flex in React Native?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, react-native

I'm with difficulties to centralize my components in screen using CSS.

See my `App.js`:

```
import { Container } from 'native-base';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import Screen from './ScreenContainer';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#FF6666',
    flex: 1
  }
});

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Container style={styles.container}>
      <Screen />
    </Container>
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

Now, see my `ScreenContainer.js`

```
import { Container, Content, Form, Input, Label, Item } from 'native-base';
import React from 'react';

import AppLogo from '../components/AppLogo';

const Screen = () => (
  <Container>
    <Content>
      <AppLogo />
      <Form>
        <Item floatingLabel last>
          <Label>Username</Label>
          <Input />
        </Item>
      </Form>
    </Content>
  </Container>
);

export default Screen;
```

This code results in this screen:

[image]

But, I want that the screen stay with this format:

[image]

When I change the code for:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FF6666',
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

My App returns this screen:

[image]

Comment: FYI, you may have more success with potential answerers understanding this question if you use the more common "center"/"centered" instead of "centralized" (particularly in the title).

Comment: Ty @CollinD, I change the question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's Done:

```
import { Container, Content, Form, Input, Label, Item } from 'native-base';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import AppLogo from '../components/AppLogo';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
  content: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%'
  },
  item: {}
});

const Screen = () => (
  <Container style={styles.container}>
    <Content contentContainerStyle={styles.content}>
      <AppLogo />
      <Form style={styles.form}>
        <Item floatingLabel last>
          <Label>Username</Label>
          <Input />
        </Item>
      </Form>
    </Content>
  </Container>
);

export default Screen;
```

Comment: TLDR: `{ alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }`

Answer (score 5):

You may want to spend some time reading through the *Layout with Flexbox* page in the React Native documentation; as this will give you a better idea of how to achieve what you're looking for.

> You can access the React Native Flexbox documentation I referred to at:
>    https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html

---

In React Native, a component can specify the layout of its children using the flexbox algorithm. Flexbox is designed to provide a consistent layout on different screen sizes.

You've already used a bit of Flexbox, whether or not you were aware, with the CSS styles `flex: 1;` and `alignItems: 'center';`.

---

#### Solution

In React Native, Flexbox works the same was as on the web except the defaults are different, with flexDirection defaulting to column instead of row.

For this reason, we can use the `alignItems` rule to a component's style  to determine the alignment of children along the secondary axis (vertical).

Adding the following rule to your children elements will cause them to take the full screen width; however, consider adding a `max-width` for landscape layouts and larger screens (e.g. a tablet):

```
childSelector {
    alignItems: stretch;
}
```

To center your container contents both horizontally and vertically, apply the following styling rules:

```
alignItems: 'center'
justifyContent: 'center'
```

Comment: I know @Trento, the problem is: the command `alignItems` isn't working how expected. :'(

Comment: The problem persists

Comment: Sorry, your question confused me. See the newly updated bottom code snippet with `alignItems` and `justifyContent`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it without flex, you can do something like this:

```html
<View style={styles.cardContent}>
    //white square 
</View>
```

```js
// This code is responsible for centering the square box in the picture:
cardContent: {
    marginTop:19,
    height:188,
    width:188,
    backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF',
    justifyContent:'center',
    marginLeft:'auto',
    marginRight:'auto',
}
```

This will be the output:

[image]

Comment: Please fix the links

Comment: I'm sorry but the question is pretty clear about solve the issue using flex.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way:

```
    <View style={{jusifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
      <Text>I'm an element</Text>
      <Text>I'm another element</Text>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

The css property `flex` will do all the alignment things very much easier for us. You can either use `class="row"` of can give inline styles like `style={{ display: 'flex, justContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'` this will perfectly align everything in center of the parent div.

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
    <div>Child1</div>
    <div>Child2</div>
</div>
```