# How to center items in Grid

Tags: css, react-native

In my react native app I'm trying to simulate grid view and center it, but currently I can't achieve it without moving last row to the center (which is incomplete). It should be aligned to the left like first row.

```js
export const GridComponent = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container} bg="amber.100">
      <Box style={styles.item} width={150} height={150} bg="blue.100" />
      <Box style={styles.item} width={150} height={150} bg="blue.100" />
      <Box style={styles.item} width={150} height={150} bg="blue.100" />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    background: 'red',
  },
  item: {
    margin: 10,
  },
});
```

[image: Not valid Grid].

Added `marginRight: 'auto'` to the item class isn't solution because then whole grid isn't centered:

[image: Not valid Grid with marginRight].

Comment: also, **grid** used a `place-items: center` that can help you (I don't know if it working on React-Native, never used it, but In Normal, React works, try and tell me it is working) it isn't working try see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971715/how-center-components-using-flex-in-react-native

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176419/targeting-flex-items-on-the-last-or-specific-row

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas can't use this property in react native.

Comment: @Paulie_D the question is about React Native, not React, so I can't use the solution which you provided